# Navigation Bar won't extend to edge of webpage

Tags: html, css, web, navigationbar

I'm trying to get my Navigation Bar to extend to the rest of the page but somehow it is looking like this: [current navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvPem.png).

Additionally, you can see that there's a white border on the top and sides, is there a way to fix? I've tried various ways but it is not changing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML & CSS code:

```
     <html>
        <head>

         <style>

    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora);
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab">

        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            }


        .nav-bar-block {

            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #F8F8F8;
            background-size: cover;
            border-bottom: 1px;
            border-bottom-color: dimgray;
            display: inline-block;

        }

        .nav-bar-block h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Lora, sans-serif;
            color: #4b4b4b;
            font-size: 45px;
            padding: 0px 400px;

        }

        .nav-bar-menu {
            list-style-type: none;  

        }

       </style>
   </head>


     <body>

      <div class="nav-bar-block">
         <h1>Title</h1>
      </div> 
    </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change .nav-bar-block to

```
display: block;
```

then you'll get the top full width (inline-block means things show up next to an element but block means they will take up the whole row of content).

```css
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            }


        .nav-bar-block {

            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #F8F8F8;
            background-size: cover;
            border-bottom: 1px;
            border-bottom-color: dimgray;
            display: block;

        }

        .nav-bar-block h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Lora, sans-serif;
            color: #4b4b4b;
            font-size: 45px;
            padding: 0px 400px;

        }

        .nav-bar-menu {
            list-style-type: none;  

        }
```

```html
     <html>
        <head>

         <style>

    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora);
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab">



       </style>
   </head>


     <body>

      <div class="nav-bar-block">
         <h1>Title</h1>
      </div> 
    </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked - any idea why there's a white border at the top? Do I need to fix my padding or..?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain — if you'd like to update your original post with the full code snippet, that would make it easier to determine. I have a feeling there's a different style that's conflicting. You can use Chrome Developer Tools by inspecting the element. Scroll to the bottom and see the box model — it'll show you if there is a padding/margin/border applied through any of the styles.

Comment: This is the full code, so I'm not sure what could be conflicting. Thank you for your help though! Appreciate it.

Comment: As an update, I had to reset the CSS style using: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS and your navbar should have full width:

```
   <html>
    <head>

     <style>

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora);
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab">

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        }


    .nav-bar-block {

        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #F8F8F8;
        background-size: cover;
        border-bottom: 1px;
        border-bottom-color: dimgray;
        display: inline-block;

    }

    .nav-bar-block h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Lora, sans-serif;
        color: #4b4b4b;
        font-size: 45px;
        padding: 0px 400px;

    }

    .nav-bar-menu {
        list-style-type: none;  

    }
    .nav-bar-block {
        /*Makes the navbar's width full*/
        width: 100%;
    }

   </style>
```

```
 <body>

  <div class="nav-bar-block">
     <h1>Title</h1>
  </div> 
</body>
```